# htaccess rewrite rule assistance

Tags: .htaccess

I need to create a rewrite rule for an htaccess file which will rewrite URL's such as:

```
http://archive.citylaw.org/bsa/2014/03.24.14/300-13-A.pdf
```

to

```
http://archive.citylaw.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/24/bsa/2014/03.24.14/300-13-A.pdf
```

The rule needs to match any link such as:

```
http://archive.citylaw.org/bsa/<file-path>
```

which is a link to a PDF file to the new location

```
http://archive.citylaw.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/24/bsa/<file-path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(bsa\/.*) /wp-content/uploads/sites/24/$1 [R]
```

The [R] tell apache to send a redirect, so the browser will update its navbar, usually this avoid browser not dealing well with non html files on rewrite.

Updated after Prix comments, I did forgot about .htaccess specificity 
Second edit

Comment: `.htaccess` rewrite rules do no start with a `/` so your rule would fail, they only start with a `/` when being used inside a virtualhost and the user explicit said `.htaccess`. As a side note, you don't need to escape `/`.

Comment: For the escaping, yes, but I think I'm too used to escape it (and its more clear for someone else reading after IMHO). thanks for the reminder, absolutely forgot about the the specificity of .htacces, would do like this assuming the file is in a /bsa directory in the DocRoot

Comment: Its not a `%{QUERY_STRING}` so you don't need that condition either the RewriteRule alone should work just fine.

Comment: @Prix you should write the answer yourself :). I'm far more used to vhosts rules on reverse proxy mode and really don't wish to get thanks for other's work.

Comment: That is clearly not a vhost issue, you just added something completely unneeded to your answer `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/bsa\/.*$` where all you had to do was remove a slash.

Comment: @Prix What I meant is that I think you deserve the points for the answer. But corrected now. (Still thinking you should write your own answer and I'll delete this one)